# Move a file after an email is sent

Tags: smtpclient

I am writing a program that looks for files in a folder, attaches the files to the MailMessage and sends an email using SmtpClient.

After the email is sent out successfully, I want to move the emailed files to a different folder.

I get this message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.". I tried Thread.Sleep() but did not work.

```
smtpClient.Send(mail);

foreach (var report in reports)
{
    string source = Path.Combine(reportsFolder, report);
    string destination = Path.Combine(sentReportsFolder, report);
    File.Move(source, destination);
}
```

Comment: How are you attaching the files to the message?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to dispose your smtpclient class:

```
smtpClient.Send(mail);
smtpClient.Dispose();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.dispose.aspx

But, when creating the class, you could use an using statemant.

Like:

```
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClent()) {
  //attach file
  smtpClient.Send();
}
```

This will ensure that, after send an email, the class will releases any resources that might be locked by the class. So, you not need to call .Dispose() explicitly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx